# Непонятное поведение функции - генератора

Tags: python, python-3.x, генераторы

Есть функция - генератор, которая принимает `n`, и если оно больше определенного числа, функция вызывает себя от `n - 1` и записываeт в генератор значение числа, умножeного на *2*. И так пока число не станет меньше или равно  определенному, тогда уже можно записать eго квадрат. Только вот сама себя она не вызывает, кто подскажет почему?

```
def pip(n):
    if n > 10:
        pip(n - 1)
        yield n * 2
    else:
        yield n ** 2
```

```
x = pip(11)
print(next(x))
```

> 22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip(n - 1)` возвращает генератор, но значения из этого генератора никак не используются (даже не запрашиваются).

Для возврата из функции-генератора всех значений из другого итератора можно использовать конструкцию `yield from` (работает [начиная с Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380)):

```
yield from pip(n - 1)
```

Это работает как такой цикл:

```
for item in pip(n - 1):
    yield item
```